# branch.io - parameter +is_first_session always false

Tags: ios, iphone, branch.io, ios10.2

I am using branch iOS SDK for sending universal links. One of my test devices now always returns the parameter +is_first_session as false.

I delete the app on the device to be tested and install the app on another device. I send the install link via message or email to the device without the app, open that link (App Store is opened) and finally install the debug version with xCode. The code works on some devices (iOS 10.1.1 and iOS 9.3) but not on an iOS 10.2. It has always worked before on the same device, so I am thinking it has something to do with the new iOS version.

Any ideas that might help? Can anybody explain how +is_first_session is determined? Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Apple introduced an unannounced change in iOS 10.2 (at Branch, we believe this may actually be a bug from Apple) that broke the logic Branch uses to differentiate between installs and re-installs. This caused some new installs on iOS 10.2 to incorrectly report `+is_first_session: false`. We have implemented a backend change to resolve the issue.

---

Alex from Branch.io here: `+is_first_session` is the variable Branch uses to determine if an app as *ever* been installed on that unique device before. This means if you have installed any version at any point in the past, you will get `false` here, which is by design as it allows you to construct customized experiences for first-time installers (vs. people who have re-installed).

If you want to bypass this for testing purposes, you'll want to use the [debug mode](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/ios/#use-debug-mode-to-simulate-fresh-installs). Once this is on, you'll get `is_first_session: true` any time the app is installed (meaning, you delete the app and reinstall it, or install a fresh build from Xcode)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps a lot. I will try that out. I just want to mention though that although debug mode is NOT on, some of the devices return +is_first_session = true when deleting the app and testing with xcode. Is that on purpose then? What's the difference there? The app has been installed on all of them at least once. Interestingly enough with debug mode NOT on reseting the advertisting identifier helps on a for example iPhone 7 (10.1.1) but not at all on the 10.2 devices.

Comment: I just tested with debug mode on (again) like this: `let branch: Branch = Branch.getTestInstance() branch.setDebug() branch.initSession.....` but with no success. `+is_first_session` is always `false` on iOS 10.2 devices. The above (in the comment) mentioned is still valid with debug mode on. I probably should mention that the code was working before I updated one of the devices to iOS 10.2.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will check with our iOS engineers and report back...perhaps something has changed in the most recent update!

Comment: This was a bug on iOS 10.2! See updated answer to resolution

Comment: @AlexBauer trying to get `is_first_session` oh iOS 12.2 using https://docs.branch.io/apps/ios/#simulate-an-install. Even in debug mode it is always `false`. Using Branch-Segment integration. Branch version 0.28.1. Maybe you could suggest a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing on iOS 13, if, in the iOS Settings app, the Privacy > Advertising > Limit Ad Tracking option is enabled (meaning the IDFA is not exposed to Branch, then the `+is_first_session` key value will always be `false`, even if the app is installed for the first time.

My takeaway from this is that the value `+is_first_session` cannot be relied on to provide useful information in all cases.